# Google Compute Instance 100% CPU Utilisation

Tags: google-compute-engine

I am running n1-standard-1 (1 vCPU, 3.75 GB memory) Compute Instance , In my android app around 80 users are online write now and cpu Utilisation of instance is 99% and my app became less responsive. Kindly suggest me the workaround and If i need to upgrade , can I do that with same instance or new instance needs to be created.

Answer (score 1):

Since your app is running already and users are connecting to it, you don't want to do the following process:

1. shut down the VM instance, keeping the boot disk and other disks
2. boot a more powerful instance, using the boot disk from step (1)
3. attach and mount any additional disks, if applicable

Instead, you might want to do the following:

1. create an additional VM instance with similar software/configuration
2. create a load balancer and add both the original and new VM to it as a backend
3. change your DNS name to point to the load balancer IP instead of the original VM instance

Now, your users will be randomly sent to a VM that's least-loaded to see the application, and you can add more VMs if your traffic increases.

You did not describe your application in detail, so it's unclear if each VM has local state (e.g., runs a database) or there's a database running externally. You will still need to figure out how to manage the stateful systems such as database or user-uploaded data from all the VM instances, which is hard to advise on given the little information in your quest.